# How to PHP Curl into & register user on AngularJS site

Tags: php, angularjs, curl

Need help from someone familiar with PHP and AngularJS to parse a registration page so I can create a Curl Function.

I am trying to create a Single Sign On experience with a partner site.  After registering on our site, we automatically register them on the partner site.  Once registered we can then use PHP Curl to create a one click login to our partner.

Unfortunately the partner site lost their main programmer and I have no AngularJS experience.  Our partner does not see the value of single sign on, so they are not willing to hire a contractor just for this.

I Need guidance on parsing their registration page so I can build a PHP curl function to automate the registration.  (I expected to see `<form>` tag, but I could not find one.)

Here is the code from their registration page:

```
<div class="togContent" ng-show="show">

    <div class="table">
        <div class="label ng-binding">Member #: </div>
        <div><input type="text" class="uppercase ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="mem.Member"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">First Name: </div>
        <div><input type="text" class="capitalize ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="mem.FirstName"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Last Name: </div>
        <div><input type="text" class="capitalize ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="mem.LastName"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Zip: </div>
        <div><input type="text" ng-keypress="validateZip($event)" maxlength="5" ng-model="mem.Zip" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength"></div>
        <div class="label filler">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="filler">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Email: </div>
        <div><input type="text" ng-model="mem.Email" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Password: </div>
        <div><input type="password" ng-model="mem.NewPassword" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Confirm Email: </div>
        <div><input type="text" ng-model="mem.Email2" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></div>
        <div class="label ng-binding">Confirm Password: </div>
        <div><input type="password" ng-model="mem.NewPassword2" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></div>
        <div><p ng-show="err.display" class="ng-binding ng-hide"></p></div>
    </div>

    <p class="clear center padtop ng-binding" style="visibility:hidden;"><input type="checkbox" name="marketingSignup" ng-model="mem.notifications" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"> Yes, I would like to receive email alerts and notifications from this site.</p>
    <div class="submitButton ng-binding" ng-click="signup()">Sign Up</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you sign up / log in a dummy user and record the POST requests that submits the data to the server. Then you get both the data structure and the URL it should be POSTED to.

Comment: Great Idea, it worked.  IF this was an answer I would give you the points. (repost as answer if you want them)

Comment: Great that you managed to solve it. I try to help out when I can - sadly I don't have time to write to write proper answers. But I hope my comments can help people to at least get on the right track. I don't really care about the points.

Comment: It was perfect.  I use developer tools all the time, but normally to parse the code, never realized it had this function!

Comment: Dev tools is great, if you use Chrome you definitely need Batarang, which is a dev tool extension for AngularJS (you get it in the normal extension webstore. You should also get acquainted with profiling (to see what makes your site slow), and resources (to manipulate local storage, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comment by [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1078488/jiml](http://JimL)  I was able to just record the post and figure out that way.  Thanks Jim!